# Laravel SELECT con WHERE NOT EXISTS de otra SELECT

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

¿Por qué al restar a una select, otra select no devuelve las preguntas restantes?

Dispongo de 2 tablas: Preguntas y Respuestas.

```
*Tablas:*
```

PREGUNTAS:

- numeroPregunta
- modalidadPregunta

RESPUESTAS:

- numeroPregunta
- respuestasCorrectas
- idUsuario
- modalidad

  *Explicación:*

La tabla "PREGUNTAS" contiene todas las preguntas de diferentes modalidades.

La tabla "RESPUESTAS" contiene cada una de las respuestas de los usuarios.
Si una pregunta se responde 4 veces bien (respuestasCorrectas=4), no se debe preguntar más esa pregunta al usuario ya que se considera SUPERADA la pregunta.

La aplicación debe seleccionar todas las preguntas de la tabla "PREGUNTAS", excepto las superadas( es decir, cuyo respuestasCorrectas >= 4) indicadas en la tabla "RESPUESTAS".

```
*Planteamiento:*
```

**SELECT** numeroPregunta FROM preguntas

**WHERE NOT EXIST**
   (**SELECT** numeroPregunta, respuestasCorrectas WHERE respuestasCorrectas >= 4 AND idUsuario = "1" AND modalidad = "administrativo")

```
*Código:*

$pregunta=Pregunta::select('preguntas.id','preguntas.preguntaTest', 'preguntas.aRespuesta', 'preguntas.bRespuesta', 'preguntas.cRespuesta', 'preguntas.dRespuesta', 'preguntas.respuestaLetra', 'preguntas.numeroPregunta','preguntas.modalidadPregunta')
     ->whereNotExists(function($query)
                    {
               $query=Respuesta::select('respuestas.numeroPregunta','respuestas.respuestasCorrectas')
    ->from('respuestas')                             ->where([['preguntas.numeroPregunta','=',$contadorPreguntas],
        ['respuestas.idUsuario','=',$id],
        ['respuestas.modalidadPregunta','=',$modalidad],
        ['respuestas.respuestasCorrectas','<','4']
                            ]);
                    })
    ->orderBy('preguntas.numeroPregunta', 'asc')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿no tienes definida una relación en los modelos Pregunta y Respuesta?

Comment: mmm no. ¿Tendrá eso algo que ver?

Comment: no es que tenga que ver, preguntaba porque pienso que relacionar Pregunta con Respuesta y Respuesta con User, facilitaría las cosas, y tal vez ya estaban definidas las relaciones pero no las estabas usando.

Answer (score 0):

El operador EXISTS devuelve TRUE si la subconsulta devuelve uno o más registros.

Es decir si su subconsulta:

```
(SELECT numeroPregunta, respuestasCorrectas WHERE respuestasCorrectas >= 4 AND idUsuario = "1" AND modalidad = "administrativo")
```

devuelve al menos un registro su consulta en realidad queda asi:

```
SELECT numeroPregunta FROM preguntas WHERE TRUE
```

De lo contrario queda

```
SELECT numeroPregunta FROM preguntas WHERE FALSE
```

Y en este ultimo caso su consulta no le devuelve nada.

Lo que le recomiendo es cambiar un poco su consulta para que valide a través el id de las preguntas en su subconsulta de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT id, numeroPregunta FROM preguntas

WHERE id not in (SELECT id WHERE respuestasCorrectas >= 4 AND idUsuario = "1" AND modalidad = "administrativo")
```